go-swagger generate panic nil pointer
When i run swagger generate spec, I get an error:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0xb3a36f]

goroutine 391 [running]:
go/types.(*Checker).handleBailout(0xc000442800, 0xc000d37bd0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/check.go:367 +0x88
panic({0xdc86c0?, 0x159c340?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:770 +0x132
go/types.(*StdSizes).Sizeof(0x0, {0x1074cb0, 0x15a6bc0})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/sizes.go:228 +0x30f
go/types.(*Config).sizeof(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/sizes.go:333
go/types.representableConst.func1({0x1074cb0?, 0x15a6bc0?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/const.go:76 +0x9e
go/types.representableConst({0x1078cb0, 0x1577e20}, 0xc000442800, 0x15a6bc0, 0xc000d36898)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/const.go:106 +0x2c7
go/types.(*Checker).representation(0xc000442800, 0xc0001abd40, 0x15a6bc0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/const.go:256 +0x65
go/types.(*Checker).representable(0xc000442800, 0xc0001abd40, 0x15a6bc0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/const.go:239 +0x26
go/types.(*Checker).shift(0xc000442800, 0xc0001ab9c0, 0xc0001abd40, {0x1077990, 0xc000d20090}, 0x14)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/expr.go:650 +0x1eb
go/types.(*Checker).binary(0xc000442800, 0xc0001ab9c0, {0x1077990, 0xc000d20090}, {0x1077510, 0xc0001d6300}, {0x10773c0, 0xc0001d6320}, 0x14, 0x449f)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/expr.go:796 +0x150
go/types.(*Checker).exprInternal(0xc000442800, 0x0, 0xc0001ab9c0, {0x1077990, 0xc000d20090}, {0x0, 0x0})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/expr.go:1416 +0x206
go/types.(*Checker).rawExpr(0xc000442800, 0x0, 0xc0001ab9c0, {0x1077990?, 0xc000d20090?}, {0x0?, 0x0?}, 0x0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/expr.go:979 +0x19e
go/types.(*Checker).expr(0xc000442800, 0x15a6c00?, 0xc0001ab9c0, {0x1077990?, 0xc000d20090?})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/expr.go:1513 +0x30
go/types.(*Checker).constDecl(0xc000442800, 0xc000c26900, {0x10773c0, 0xc0001d6260}, {0x1077990, 0xc000d20090}, 0x0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/decl.go:488 +0x2f1
go/types.(*Checker).objDecl(0xc000442800, {0x107f420, 0xc000c26900}, 0x0)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/decl.go:191 +0xa49
go/types.(*Checker).packageObjects(0xc000442800)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/resolver.go:693 +0x4dd
go/types.(*Checker).checkFiles(0xc000442800, {0xc000d22000, 0x1, 0x1})
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/check.go:408 +0x1a5
go/types.(*Checker).Files(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/go/types/check.go:372
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages.(*loader).loadPackage(0xc0000c27e0, 0xc00080f140)
        C:/Users/alant/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.9.3/go/packages/packages.go:1055 +0xa72
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages.(*loader).loadRecursive.func1()
        C:/Users/alant/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.9.3/go/packages/packages.go:854 +0x1a9
sync.(*Once).doSlow(0x0?, 0x0?)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/sync/once.go:74 +0xc2
sync.(*Once).Do(...)
        C:/Program Files/Go/src/sync/once.go:65
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages.(*loader).loadRecursive(0x0?, 0x0?)
        C:/Users/alant/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.9.3/go/packages/packages.go:842 +0x4a
golang.org/x/tools/go/packages.(*loader).loadRecursive.func1.1(0x0?)
        C:/Users/alant/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.9.3/go/packages/packages.go:849 +0x26
created by golang.org/x/tools/go/packages.(*loader).loadRecursive.func1 in goroutine 79
        C:/Users/alant/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.9.3/go/packages/packages.go:848 +0x94

That said, when I run the same command on another device, everything generates fine. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem? I reinstalled the package, it didn't help. So the anotations themselves have nothing to do with it. I generate the same thing on both devices. I also reinstalled golang itself, but to no avail.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
